# ASP.Net MVC3 - Can we apply custom client validation at the level of EditorTemplate

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive

If one of the fields in the Model is bound to a EditorTemplate, will the javascript unobtrusive data-val-* parameters be generated for the EditorTemplate if the field in the Model is decorated with validation attributes.

Also, if I apply a custom client validation, by implementing a validation attribute with IClientValidatable, and decorate this field with that custom attribute, does it generate the data-val-* attributes  for the EditorTemplate in the client side, for the client rules I add in the custom validaiton attribute?

I don't seem to get it working, it does not emit the client side attributes for me.

This is a simpler and part of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378520/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-unobtrusive-validation-for-editor-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.
Thanks to Brad Wilson on other forum, actually if we have any input control in it, for which a validation can be applied, it is generating data-val-* attributes. 
I was checking in some other scenario, it was not working for me, but a normal simple case is generating those attributes.